# focus() Jquery calls Infinite alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $(document).foundation();
    var user_name_input = $('#user_name');

    user_name_input.focus(function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

When I focus on #user_name  I get infinite alerts.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
user_name_input.focus(function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
```

every time a focus happens on an input, the alert is raised removing the focus.

Once you click `Ok` for the alert box, the focus for the input box is regained and another alert raised.

Thus, a never ending cycle of alerts and focus